# Can I change CPU governor?

Tags: kernel, cpufreq, governor

When I run the command:

```
cpupower frequency-info --governors
```

I get the following message:

```
this output available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
```

I want to change it to 'ondemand'. How can I do that?

Comment: What exactly is your aim, please?

Comment: I wanted to change governor to 'ondemand'.

Answer (score 0):

CPU governors are are low level drivers in the kernel.

If you want to add them you have to build a custom kernel including them.